People who drink some kind of juice dissolved
I watched this Japanese animation when I was child, maybe 35-40 years ago. People liked to drink some juice, it was very popular and they got some rewards if they collect a specific number of bottles. Main hero was a boy, who collected these bottles.
But later some people who drank too much of this juice started dissolving. And then some alien invasion started. These aliens sold this juice to eliminate people.
The boy started to fight them and joined some ship crew. 
Don't remember more details.

Perhaps this juice you mention is the "Boa Juice" from Sora Tobu Yureisen?

looks like it is

Thanks to Krazer, this is the anime that featured 'Boa Juice' which dissolved people when they drank too much of it.
Searching by 'Boa Juice', I found the film's actual title: Flying Phantom Ship (1969). From IMDb:

Hayato's peaceful life with his parents and his dog is brought to a dramatic, terrible end when a giant robot, said to be sent from a flying ghost ship, devastates the city, killing hundreds including Hayato's parents. Shortly before his death, Hayato's father reveals that he is not really their son. Hayato is now alone, struggling in this strange new world left after the disaster, where giant machines and monsters control the world.


Added some details since it was a little bare.

I should wait 5 hours before I can accept it,
